# What does it mean to declare an item of type contract?

Tags: solidity, interfaces

Wasn't quite sure how to word the title, but in the following code:

```
contract KittyInterface {
...
}

contract ZombieFeeding is ZombieFactory {

KittyInterface kittyContract;

}
```

what is the declaration **KittyInterface kittyContract;** creating? I saw that it can be be initialized with KittyInterface **kittyContract = KittyInterface(ckAddress);** where ckAddress is the address of the interface contract that is being used.

I read the contracts section of the solidity documentation but it hasn't really answered my question. If anyone can forward me to a resource to better understand this I would be very appreciative!

Comment: It declares a storage variable.

Answer (score 1):

It declares a storage variable of type `KittyInterface`.  You can also define a storage variable to be a contract type and then use it in your contract instance.

An example is given in the solidity docs: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.1/contracts.html#creating-contracts

```
contract OwnedToken {
    // `TokenCreator` is a contract type that is defined below.
    // It is fine to reference it as long as it is not used
    // to create a new contract.
    TokenCreator creator;
    address owner;
    bytes32 name;

    // This is the constructor which registers the
    // creator and the assigned name.
    constructor(bytes32 _name) public {

        owner = msg.sender;
        name = _name;

        // We perform an explicit type conversion from `address`
        // to `TokenCreator` and assume that the type of
        // the calling contract is `TokenCreator`, there is
        // no real way to verify that.
        // This does not create a new contract.
        creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender);

    }

    function transfer(address newOwner) public {
        if (msg.sender != owner) return;

        // We ask the creator contract if the transfer
        // should proceed by using a function of the
        // `TokenCreator` contract defined below. If
        // the call fails (e.g. due to out-of-gas),
        // the execution also fails here.
        if (creator.isTokenTransferOK(owner, newOwner))
            owner = newOwner;
    }

    [...rest snipped...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Type includes the functions and a deployment address, once its instantiated. So, instances will have methods that correspond to the contract functions.

For example, a function might take an address for a KittyContract and then use it for something. Since your example stored exactly one, let us say that's part of the constructor.

```
constructor(address k) public {
  kittyContract = KittyContract(k);
}
```

Now, we're all set to

```
kittyContract.anyFunction(args...)
```

or if it returns something

```
bool success = kittyContract.anyFunction()...
```

Hope it helps.